# ntp.conf function and format for server keyword

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I have 4 redhat boxes that are each sync'ed by their own arbiter gps clock.  These are acting as time sources for the rest of my network.

Can I include all four boxes in the peer statements in ntp.conf, so I only have to deal with one ntp.conf, as in:

peer rh1

peer rh2

peer rh3

peer rh4

Or do I have to leave out the local hostname for each ntp.conf, as in:

rh1:

peer rh2

peer rh3

peer rh4

rh2:

peer rh1

peer rh3

peer rh4

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried this? For some reason I seem to recall that there is a builtin restrict statement that will make ntp ignore connecting back to itself. Also: Why are you not setting them up as peers o each other?

Comment: I'm doing the second option (leaving out the local box).  I have not tried the first because I am uncertain that it will actually 'fail', rather than just generate less than optimal or even erroneous behavior.  The reason I typed 'server' instead of 'peer' is because I'm an idiot that can't read my own files.  The real files all say 'peer'.   Sorry about that.

Comment: server vs peer corrected in OP

Comment: OK, tried to use the same ntp.conf for all 4 boxes.  What comes up is that the local box displays as .INIT. and str 16 if I do an ntpq -p.  I guess this is the same as effectively taking itself out of consideration to avoid any self-sync or other problems, but the .INIT. is a bit confusing.

Comment: the .INIT string just means "i have not even been able to connect to this host. still trying to initialize a connection"

Comment: I understand that.  I guess my point is that yes, apparently ntpd does take the local box out of consideration, but why is it even trying to contact it in the first place?

Comment: It is trying to contact it because you told it to try. Given the choice between showing or not showing that information I think showing the infformation is the correct behavior. This way you know that it is configured to talk to the local machine but ntp is not letting it.

Comment: OK, said that way it makes sense.